# Create array of "1 - number of rows" for each factor R

Tags: r, for-loop

Brain and search are failing me. I have several levels of a factor, we'll call them A, B, and C.

```
abc <- c("a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "c")
```

I want to have another array labelled 1 through the number of each factor.

```
output <- c(1,2,1,1,2,3)
```

Is this a for loop job, or something else?

For loops aren't my strong suit, and my attempts have failed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option in `base R` is to a group by sequence with `ave`

```
ave(seq_along(abc), abc, FUN = seq_along)
#1] 1 2 1 1 2 3
```

---

Or in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
rowid(abc)
```